# Javascript new object in each function not working as I imagined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, for-loop, underscore.js, new-operator

I'm creating a new Backbone Model during a forEach loop, then running another forEach loop inside and creating another Backbone Model and passing it back to the previous Model as a attribute.

However by the end the child Models seem to be added to everything first level model.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZBvV4/

```
var page =
 { rows:
    [
      { layout: '1:1:1'
      , columns:
        [ 
          { widgets: 
              [
                {
                  type: 'twitter'
                }
              , {
                  type: 'facebook'
                }
              ]
          }
        , { widgets: 
              [
                {
                  type: 'image-slider'
                }
              , {
                  type: 'instagram'
                }
              ]
          }
        , { widgets: 
              [
                {
                  type: 'instagram'
                }
              ]
          }
        ]
      }
    , { layout: '2:1'
      , columns:
        [ 
          { widgets: 
              [
                {
                  type: 'twitter'
                }
              ]
          }
        , { widgets: 
              [
                {
                  type: 'image-slider'
                }
              ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
 }

var app = {
  models: {}
, collections: {}
, views: {}
}

app.models.Row = Backbone.Model.extend({
  childColumns: []
})

app.models.Column = Backbone.Model.extend({
  childWidgets: []
})

var renderedRows = []

_.each(page.rows, function (row, rowIndex) {
  ////////////// * ROWS * //////////////
  var rowModel = new app.models.Row({
    layout: page.rows[rowIndex].layout
  })
  renderedRows.push(rowModel)

  _.each(row.columns, function (column, columnIndex) {
    ////////////// * COLUMN * //////////////
    var columnModel = new app.models.Column()
    rowModel.childColumns.push(columnModel)
  })
})

console.log('first row child columns', renderedRows[0].childColumns)
console.log('second row child columns', renderedRows[1].childColumns)
```

Comment: Probably the most egregious misuse of white space I've seen in a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening due to how you're defining your models.

```
app.models.Row = Backbone.Model.extend({
  childColumns: []
})
```

The issue is that `childColumns` is being set to an empty array, `[]`, in the definition. `new` does not create a new array for you each time, it assigns the same array reference to each model. This means that same array is being referenced by all `Row` entries that you create.

Instead of having a single array referenced, you'll want to create a new array each time you create a new entry:

```
app.models.Row = Backbone.Model.extend({
  childColumns: null
})

app.models.Column = Backbone.Model.extend({
  childWidgets: null
})

// ...

_.each(page.rows, function (row, rowIndex) {
  var rowModel = new app.models.Row({
    layout: page.rows[rowIndex].layout
  })
  // Initialize a new array here
  rowModel.childColumns = []
  renderedRows.push(rowModel)

  _.each(row.columns, function (column, columnIndex) {
    var columnModel = new app.models.Column()
    // Initialize a new array here
    columnModel.childWidgets = []
    rowModel.childColumns.push(columnModel)
  })
})
```

Here is a jsFiddle with the fix: http://jsfiddle.net/5Epxz/1/

You could also do the array initialization in the model's `initialize` method if you wanted it to be more Backbone-ish.